# TSQL Order By Specific Value

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I need to order my results such that all items with the status column being a specific value come up first, then by date.

I tried this:

```
SELECT Id, Status, CreatedAt FROM Table
ORDER BY (Status=1) DESC, CreatedAt
```

I figured I'd get a bool value on (Status=1) so ordering by DESC to put the true (1) values on the top.

But I'm getting a syntax error.  Is this possible and if so what is the correct syntax?

Thanks!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can use [`CASE`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181765.aspx) also in the `ORDER BY`:

```
SELECT Id, Status, CreatedAt 
FROM Table
ORDER BY 
   CASE WHEN Status = 1 THEN 0 ELSE 1 END ASC, 
   CreatedAt ASC
```

Comment: Thanks very much, I thought it might be the ORDER BY CASE but have never used it before and the other stuff I read on it didn't seem to fit exactly.  Awesome!

Answer (score 5):

Try this

```
SELECT Id, Status, CreatedAt FROM Table
ORDER BY (case when Status=1 then 1 else 2 end), CreatedAt
```